# How to get a length of this JSON Object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following object stored in my LocalStorage, How do I get the .length of everything? I'm trying to get the total amount of records (without DT_RowID)?

This is what I'm working with:

```
  const cartLength = Object.values(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'))).flat().length;
  console.log("JSON obj length: ", cartLength);
```

here is my json object (as is)

```
{
  "15894903752910": {
    "Name": "John",
    "Grade": "",
    "Gender": "F",
    "DOB": "2013/07/10",
    "DT_RowId": "15894903752910" <--- this must be excluded in the 'items' count
  },
{
  "15894903752911": {
    "Name": "Jane",
    "Grade": "",
    "Gender": "F",
    "DOB": "2003/07/10",
    "DT_RowId": "15894903752910" <--- this must be excluded in the 'items' count
  }

....
}

The result of this should be 2 records and 8 items
```

[image]

Comment: Length in what units?

Comment: Can you paste your json object in the question?

Comment: Please show the result you expect to get. Otherwise, we're all just guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very confusing question but to get a count of all the record keys, excluding `DT_RowId`, something like this...

```js
const todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'))
const records = Object.values(todos)
console.log('total records', records.length)

const itemLength = records.map(r => Object.keys(r).filter(k => k !== 'DT_RowId'))
  .flat().length
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to count the keys:

```
Object.keys(myObject).length
```

Is that what you wanted?